# Move Processing from the View to a controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Currently we have a view that does some heavy processing to create an XML css feed that we send to a client.  Here is a snippet of code that does some processing:

```
@foreach (Models.BVModels cat in ViewBag.BVSubCategories)
{
    <Category>
        @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cat.LinkName))
        {
            <ExternalId>(cat.LinkName)</ExternalId>
        }
        else
        {
            <ExternalId>cat.Title</ExternalId>
        }
        <ParentExternalId>cat.ParentName</ParentExternalId>
        <Name>cat.Title</Name>
        @if (cat.Brand.ToLower() == "[hardcoded value]" && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(cat.ID))
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cat.LinkName) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(cat.ParentName))
            {
                <CategoryPageUrl><![CDATA[[URL]/gallery/@cat.ParentName.ToLower()/@cat.LinkName.ToLower()]]></CategoryPageUrl>
            }
            string imageName = cat.ID + ".jpg";
            <ImageUrl>[URL]/imageeditor/@imageName</ImageUrl>
        }
        else if (cat.Brand.ToLower() == "[BRAND]")
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cat.LinkName))
            {
                <CategoryPageUrl><![CDATA[[URL]/product/category/@cat.ID/@cat.LinkName.ToLower()]]></CategoryPageUrl>
            }
            string imagename = cat.ID + ".jpg";
            <ImageUrl>[URL]/image/getdvimagebypageidandimageid/@cat.ID/1/@imagename</ImageUrl>
        }
        else
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cat.LinkName))
            {
                <CategoryPageUrl>[URL]</CategoryPageUrl>
            }
        }
        </Category>
}
```

I need to move this to a controller instead of keeping this on the view.  This was done quickly to create the feed at one time, but now is way to slow. Not to mention there are a lot of hard coded values and some processing that needs to be cleaned up. Right now this cshtml page does not have a @model directive it is pulling the data from the ViewBag.  I want to push this to the controller and clean up this page.  Can I pass the ViewBag to the Controller and process?  I am rusty on MVC and could a small shove in the right direction.  So I want to call this controller ActionResult pass in the ViewBag and return an XML string that has been formatted as below.

Thanks.

Comment: You won't be able to use Razor code from within the controller, if that's what you're after. You can use XmlDocument or LINQ-to-XML (starting with XDocument) to build an XML file from code. I've used code inspired by [this blog post](https://seattlesoftware.wordpress.com/2008/08/22/serializing-exceptions-to-xml/) to serialize objects to XML, if that's the root of what you're trying to do

Comment: do you mean rss feed and not css?

Comment: Correct.  Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

I created a new controller for the feed that pulls the data from the database and return it in collections that I can iterate over and return the XML string.  This replaced the long processing (20 minutes) over the ViewBag.  Now I will tighten up the code and put some scrubbing in place to clean it up.

THanks.

John